# Navigation Transition blink/overlap with fast user interaction

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a xaml page with a next/previous button in the Application Bar.  the navigation is to a new instance of the same page (for browsing forward and backwards through a checklist of questions).  the ApplicationBar is available before the navigation slide transition is complete and if the user clicks the buttons quickly in succession, the transitions overlap and look messy.  is there a way to abort a transition if there is one in progress, to avoid the flicker?

Comment: Programmatically build the Application bar. Then you can disable it until you need it to be available. If you build it in XAML it sits outside of what you are allowed to access so you can't manipulate it.

Comment: thanks for the reply AMR.  i'd be interested to leave the ApplicationBar buttons unchanged because they at least allow for faster navigation for the user.  the slidetransition looks well except that blinks/flickers under fast navigation.  it's not the end of the world, but i was curious to see if the flicker could be avoied without compromising on navigation speed.

Comment: You can build the application bar in the back end code and have it look exactly the same as it does now. The only difference is that you will be able to prevent people from navigating before the navigation animation is finished. Thus preventing them from navigating and causing it to flicker

Comment: hi AMR, thanks for the reply but i think you've misunderstood my last comment, i actually want the user to be able to navigate quickly.  for this app scenario, there is no point limiting the user experience for the sake of eye candy.  i was only trying to find out if it could be avoided.  thanks anyway!